# c++: check array's order

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have tried to write a bool function, accepted an array and a bool dec. If dec is true than the function will check it's descending and return true if it's descending. If dec is false than the function will return true if it's ascending.

If I test the array with this function, it should return false, but it gives true, and I don't know why.
Can anyone help? thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>

#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

bool isSorted(int array[], int size, bool dec) //false decending
{
    bool check = true;

    if (dec == false)
        for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
            if (array[i]>array[i + 1])
            {
                check = false;
                cout << "false";
            }

    else
        for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
            if (array[i]<array[i + 1])
                check = false;

    return check;
}


int main() {
    int n;
    bool asc=true;
    bool result;
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 4, 3, 0 };
    n = 5;

    result = isSorted(arr, n, asc);
    cout << result;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: For real code, this would be a call to `std::is_sorted`.

Comment: Take care you're staying inside bounds using this index: `array[i + 1]`

Answer (score 3):

You have an off-by-one error: when you reach the last element and `i` is one less than `size`, `arrat[i+1]` is referencing an element past the end of the array.

Since changing `check` to `false` is a "one way street", you can simplify your function by returning `false` as soon as you detect a wrong order; return `true` when you reach the end of the function.

You can also move the ascending/descending check inside the loop to make the code even more uniform:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size-1 ; i++) {
    if (des && (array[i]<array[i + 1])
    || !des && (array[i]>array[i + 1])) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

The value you pass to the function is named `asc` while the parameter for it is `dec`. Check again if you actually do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing beyond the boundary of the array, change the loop to

```
  for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
```

So when you get to `size - 2` you compare the last two elements and you're done.

Also you can return immediately after finding an exception instead of completing the iteration.